# convert std:vector to NSArray

Tags: c++, vector, nsarray, objective-c++

Is there a good way to convert a `vector<int32_t>` to an `NSArray` of `NSNumber` or is looping and adding to an `NSMutableArray` pretty much the only way?

Comment: NSArray cannot contain elements of the primitive type NSInteger.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII actually, it *can*. i've demonstrated exactly this in my answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you have a vector of objects, you can do the following:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:&vector[0] count:vector.size()];
```

However, if your vector contains primitive types, such as `NSInteger`, `int`, `float`, etc., you would have to manually loop the values in the vector and convert them to a `NSNumber` first.

Comment: Be very careful with this approach with regard to the lifetime of the vector's objects!

Comment: This answers my question.  I do have a `vector<int32_t>` so unfortunately I have to loop through all the values anyway.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get "Cannot initialize a parameter of type 'const __unsafe_unretained id *' with an rvalue of type..."

Comment: @Greg What's the second type? This was done before the advent of ARC, so you probably need to cast the pointer.

Comment: Sorry, was in a rush and I misunderstood your answer. You're right-- it works. I think it would be clearer to clarify with something like "a vector of Objective-C objects". I'd be willing to change my vote, if edited.

Comment: @Greg I see no reason to update this answer currently and bump it to the front paste, and your comment *is* valid, so I'll just keep it as-is for now. Not like those two rep points mean anything anyhow.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you *can* create an `NSArray` of `NSInteger`s from a `std::vector<NSInteger>` by using the following approach:

```
// thrown together as a quick demo. this could be improved.
NSArray * NSIntegerVectorToNSArrayOfNSIntegers(const std::vector<NSInteger>& vec) {

  struct MONCallback {
    static const void* retain(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void* value) {
      /* nothing to do */
      return value;
    }

    static void release(CFAllocatorRef allocator, const void* value) {
      /* nothing to do */
    }

    static CFStringRef copyDescription(const void* value) {
      const NSInteger i(*(NSInteger*)&value);
      return CFStringCreateWithFormat(0, 0, CFSTR("MON - %d"), i);
    }

    static Boolean equal(const void* value1, const void* value2) {
      const NSInteger a(*(NSInteger*)&value1);
      const NSInteger b(*(NSInteger*)&value2);
      return a == b;
    }
  };

  const CFArrayCallBacks callbacks = {
    .version = 0,
    .retain = MONCallback::retain,
    .release = MONCallback::release,
    .copyDescription = MONCallback::copyDescription,
    .equal = MONCallback::equal
  };

  const void** p((const void**)&vec.front());
  NSArray * result((NSArray*)CFArrayCreate(0, p, vec.size(), &callbacks));
  return [result autorelease];  
}

void vec_demo() {
  static_assert(sizeof(NSInteger) == sizeof(NSInteger*), "you can only use pointer-sized values in a CFArray");

  std::vector<NSInteger> vec;
  for (NSInteger i(0); i < 117; ++i) {
    vec.push_back(i);
  }
  CFShow(NSIntegerVectorToNSArrayOfNSIntegers(vec));
}
```

However, you will need to be very cautious regarding your use of this collection. Foundation expects the elements to be `NSObject`s. If you pass it into an external API that expects an array of `NSObject`s, it will probably cause an error (read: `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` in `objc_msgSend`).

Usually, one would convert them to `NSNumber`. I would use this `NSArray` of `NSInteger`s in my program only if another another API *needed* it (Apple has a few) -- They just don't play very well together.

Comment: I actually meant `NSNumber` but +1 for a fascinating answer!